# Bash in Mac OSX terminal: "command not found". Why?

Tags: macos, bash

When I want to enter a command (for example `say`) it returns a message like this:

```
bash: say: command not found.
```

It appears every time I write a command. What do I have to do?

Answer (score 2):

Have you made sure that your $PATH variable is set?

You can check by typing this in the Terminal:

```
echo $PATH
```

If nothing is listed after you try that... it might be part of the problem.

(For more information, you could try checking this page out:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-command-not-found-error-and-how-to-get-rid-of-it/)

Comment: Just for reference the default $PATH variable should return the following in a Snow Leopard installation at least.


/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

Answer (score 1):

If you are using your own command and you are in it's directory you may need to add `./` before it.

before:

```
user$ my-command
```

after:

```
user$ ./my-command
```

Or add it to your path

Answer (score 0):

If you use quotes it will not display them, but tell you that there is no command. Many tutorials use quotes to show what you should type in, but sometimes they don't say "Without the quotes."

Answer (score 0):

In the username in OSX, sometimes the $ is included meaning that you do not have to include it in your command.

Answer (score 0):

Let's find out if the *say* executable (program) is in the right place. In the terminal, type

```
which say
```

you should see

```
/usr/bin/say
```